# NoSuchObjectException when using fixed port number in method 'exportObject' of class UnicastRemoteObject

Tags: java, rmi

This is the code my application had before I changed it:

```
Static Map <String,MKRSingleton> servStubs = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String,MKRSingleton>);
public synchronized Object test(String type) throws Exception
{

MKRSingleton = (MKRSingleton) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(MKRSingletonRemote,0);
servStubs.put(type,MKRSingleton);

}
```

We had issues when we moved this code on cloud instance. Problem seems to be that since port number passed is zero so RMI runtime chose anonymous
port on which the remote object receives calls, however, its not compatible with  cloud (only static port numbers for incoming requests) hence was not working. I changed the code to pass static port:

```
public synchronized Object test(String type) throws Exception
{

MKRSingleton = (MKRSingleton) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(MKRSingletonRemote,portNo); // portNo um getting from a property file with value like 40000
servStubs.put(type,MKRSingleton);

}
```

Its working on cloud instances now, however, on a particular unix box only (non-cloud) um getting below error ( it is working on some unix boxes):

```
java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:255)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:142)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:178)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:132)
```

Not keeping a strong reference should not be an issue here as it was working fine before my change, so need your help to figure out what could the reason of the error ?

Answer (score 0):

> Not keeping a strong reference should not be an issue here as it was working fine before my change, so need your help to figure out what could the reason of the error ?

Not keeping a strong reference is the *only* issue here. The remote object has been DGC'd and locally garbage-collected. That's the meaning of the exception.

The difference is attributable to DGC lease renewal failures over the Internet. That's why you should keep a strong reference to the remote object, or, if you exported a Registry from your JVM, to the Registry: in both cases, in a static variable. The Registry will keep alive any objects bound to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, apart from passing the static port numbers in the method, I did not change anything. We rolled back the code (it is back to passing 0) and not getting exception so it is still mystery for me.

Comment: When you've tried it with a strong reference let me know.